# Grid item not filling the specified area?

Tags: css

Currently learning grid, so sorry if this is an obvious answer.

I'm doing a simple CSS grid layout, trying to get the "sidebar" div to fill the area from row 1 to row 4, to make a single column. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="sidebar"></div>
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="main-content"></div>
      <div class="announcement-card"></div>
      <div class="trending-card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container div {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #0ea5e9;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
}
```

For some reason, I can get the "header" element to fill the columns I specified, but I can't get the sidebar to fill the rows. Might be overlooking something simple, but I just don't see it.

I tried simply moving the sidebar to a different row using the following code:

```
.sidebar {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

This worked, and the one blue box that represents the sidebar moved to the third row. So I know that I can move the element's row, but I can't make the element span across multiple rows.

Comment: Why have you given the sidebar div a fixed height of 200px - did you mean every item within it? Please show us the relevant HTML.

Comment: I added the HTML. I added a fixed height to the divs within the grid container thinking that was how I could make the grid items bigger, though I see now that it was a mistake thanks to someone else's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code which is causing the problem. It sets every cell in your grid to the the same height, so the sidebar height is 200px and the header height is also 200px.

```
.grid-container div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Once you remove that style, everything works fine:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2px;
}

.grid-container div {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #0ea5e9;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div>d1</div>
  <div>d2</div>
  <div>d3</div>
  <div>d4</div>
  <div>d5</div>
  <div>d6</div>
  <div>d7</div>
  <div>d8</div>
  <div>d9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it, but I'm confused. Why does setting a fixed height to the grid cells not allow you to span the item across multiple rows?

Comment: The grid itself is like a framework or a scaffold ... the items you put into a grid are placed within that scaffold but they still retain some independence. If you set a fixed height on a grid item, the scaffold can't override that.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please [mark my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the accepted answer. That way, I will earn reputation points for my efforts.

Comment: Sorry, just did it now. First time on this site LOL.